# Universal references and local classes

Tags: c++, forward, forwarding, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

In my code below I have a function which accepts "universal reference" (`F&&`). The function also has an inner class which accepts an object of `F&&` in its constructor. Is `F&&` still a universal reference at that point? I.e. is `F` still considered to be a deduced type?

In other words, should I use `std::forward<F>` or `std::move` in the constructor initialization list?

```
#include "tbb/task.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

template<class F>
auto Async(F&& f) -> std::future<decltype(f())>
{
    typedef decltype(f()) result_type;

    struct Task : tbb::task
    {
        Task(F&& f) : f_(std::forward<F>(f)) {} // is forward correct here?

        virtual tbb::task* execute()
        {
            f_();
            return nullptr;
        }

        std::packaged_task<result_type()> f_;
    };

    auto task = new (tbb::task::allocate_root()) Task(std::forward<F>(f));
    tbb::task::enqueue(*task);
    return task->f_.get_future();
}


int main()
{
    Async([]{ std::cout << "Hi" << std::endl; }).get();
}
```

[Live demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb20145b0374c462)

Comment: The cool kids are calling them [_forwarding references_](https://twitter.com/stefanusdutoit/status/510503393702342656) now not universal references. (Cos [there ain't no such thing as a universal reference.](http://accu.org/content/conf2014/JonathanWakely-tanstaaur-accu2014.pdf))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is `F&&` still a universal reference at that point? I.e. is `F` still considered to be a deduced type?

This kind of confusion is why I dislike the term universal reference ... [there's no such thing](http://accu.org/content/conf2014/JonathanWakely-tanstaaur-accu2014.pdf).

I prefer to understand code in terms of lvalue references and rvalue references, and the rules of reference collapsing and template argument deduction.

When the function is called with an lvalue of type `L` the argument `F` will be deduced as `L&`, and by the reference collapsing rules `F&&` is just `L&`. In the `Task` constructor nothing changes, `F&&` is still `L&` so the constructor takes an lvalue reference that is bound to the lvalue passed to `Async`, and so you don't want to move it, and `forward` is appropriate because that preserves the value category, forwarding the lvalue as an lvalue. (Moving from the lvalue would surprise the caller of `Async`, who would not be expecting an lvalue to get silently moved.)

When the function is called with an rvalue of type `R` the argument `F` will be deduced as `R`, and so `F&&` is `R&&`. In the `Task` constructor nothing changes, `F&&` is still `R&&` so the constructor takes an rvalue reference that is bound to the rvalue passed to `Async`, and so you *could* move it, but `forward` is also appropriate because that preserves the value category, forwarding the rvalue as an rvalue.

At CppCon last week Herb Sutter announced that the preferred term for a "universal reference" is now **forwarding reference** because that better describes what they are used for.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The realization that std::forward simply means preserving the value category brings a lot of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The ctor **is not** a universal reference, but a bog-standard rvalue-reference, or an lvalue-reference. Trouble with your construction is you have no idea which, just that it mirrors `Async` (which might be enough)!

In order to be a universal-reference, the type would have to be deduced *for that call*, and not sometime earlier for a somewhat-related call.

`std::forward` i still appropriate there, as the outer functions argument really should be passed on to the created object with preserved move-/copy-semantics.